# values in torch.nn.conv2d and torch.nn.Linear

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am confiused how to get the `out_channels` in `torch.nn.Conv2d` and the `in_features, out_features` in `torch.nn.Linear`.
For example I have a non-color 28*28 image input.
the `in_channels = 1,kernel_size=5,padding=2` how can I figure the `out_channels`.
After the convolutional, I want to make a linear layer.
How do I figure the values of `in_features, out_features` ?

Answer (score 0):

The choice of `out_channels` is up to you, it's the number of filters you want your convolutional layer to compute. The higher this number is, the heavier the layer will be, but on the  other hand the more features it will be able to learn (theoretically).

After going through the convolution (assuming `out_channels = C`), your data will have shape `(C, 28, 28)`. In other words, one sample contains `28*28*C` numbers / dimensions. It is this number that you need to input as `in_features` for the following linear layer. Then again, `out_features` is up to you.

I **strongly** suggest that you read and learn about neural networks (and their typical convolutional and linear layers) before attempting to use them to make magic happen. Without the required knowledge about them, you will at best be able to produce results that you don't really understand, and at worst issues that you don't know how to fix. It takes time to learn, but it really is worth it.